# Customize spin box arrows

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to customize the arrows of a spin box.

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: inner-spin-button !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

This is what I want to get.

[image: This is what I want to get.]

Where should I start??
(Do I have to use jQuery widget or javascript to customize it?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Screenshot (Chrome, macOS):**

[image]

**Code:**

```css
input[type="number"] {
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  outline: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2050%2067%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%3E%3Cg%20fill%3D%22none%22%20stroke-width%3D%222%22%3E%3Cline%20x1%3D%221%22%20x2%3D%2250%22%20y1%3D%2233.5%22%20y2%3D%2233.5%22%20stroke%3D%22%23D8D8D8%22%2F%3E%3Cpolyline%20transform%3D%22translate(25%2020)%20rotate(45)%20translate(-25%20-20)%22%20points%3D%2219%2026%2019%2014%2032%2014%22%20stroke%3D%22%23000%22%2F%3E%3Cpolyline%20transform%3D%22translate(25%2045)%20rotate(225)%20translate(-25%20-45)%22%20points%3D%2219%2052%2019%2039%2032%2039%22%20stroke%3D%22%23000%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
  background-position: center right;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  caret-color: transparent;
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  height: 34px;
  width: 23px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="1" />
```

So, it can be done. But customizations like this are usually very brittle (even if you add in the necessary cross-browser properties, which I haven't done; this only works in webkit), and can hurt usability. You're probably better off using the platform's native controls.

Comment: what's the browser support for this? Is `-webkit-` all it takes or should one think after all to rebuild the whole implementation in pure JS? Will `-moz-` `-ms-` or no-prefix just work?

Comment: As written, this only works in modern webkit (it's using webkit-specific properties). There are other vendor-specific properties needed to make it work in other browsers. I don't think `-moz` and `-ms` have equivalent properties, but they have other ones that can be used to accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 2):

My answer try of fix your problem with css pure, for example with `input[type=number] {}` you can put all of rules to change the look of the input

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: inner-spin-button !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue !important;
  border: 2.5px solid red !important;
}

input[type=number] {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c !important;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
```

Comment: This is the best answer. I was looking for a way to achieve this by pure CSS. Thanks!